# Replacing NA found with filter() using lapply() when all df do not have NA

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I've been having trouble trying to get lapply to replace NAs in a dataframe that I find using a call to filter().

```
tib <- as_tibble(data.frame("Group"= c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), "Color" = c("Red", "Red", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue"), "Value" = c(5,NA,6,NA,16,12,4,5,6,10,12,17)))

> list.tib <- split(tib, tib$Group)
> list.tib
$`A`
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Group Color Value
  <fct> <fct> <dbl>
1 A     Red       5
2 A     Red      NA
3 A     Red       6
4 A     Blue     NA
5 A     Blue     16
6 A     Blue     12

$B
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Group Color Value
  <fct> <fct> <dbl>
1 B     Red       4
2 B     Blue     17
```

I want to replace the NA within [["A"]] with another value using lapply.

If I try to assign the NA an arbitrary value (here I use 50) using either "<-" or "=" it get errors stating "could not find function "filter<-"

```
> lapply(list.tib, function(x) filter(x, is.na(Value))$Value <- 50)
Error in filter(x, is.na(Value))$Value <- 50 : 
  could not find function "filter<-"
```

I tried another approach using a different format for designating the values I wanted but ended up with a different type of error.

```
> lapply(list.tib, function(x) x[which(is.na(x$Value)),]$Value <- 50)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Value", value = 50) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Which I think throws an error because [["B"]] does not have any NAs, and I'm trying to set numeric(0) to a value of 50.

I would like a function that would provide the output of:

```
> list.tib
$`A`
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Group Color Value
  <fct> <fct> <dbl>
1 A     Red       5
2 A     Red      50
3 A     Red       6
4 A     Blue     50
5 A     Blue     16
6 A     Blue     12

$B
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Group Color Value
  <fct> <fct> <dbl>
1 B     Red       4
2 B     Blue     17
```

I am able to get this desired result if I do something like:

```
list.tib$A[which(is.na(list.tib$A$Value)),]$Value <- 50
```

But that is not generalizable. I think lapply() is the call for the job, but I can't get it to assign values to specific variables of an observation.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mutate` and `ifelse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

lapply(list.tib, function(x) x %>% mutate(Value = ifelse(is.na(Value), 50, Value)))
```

Or `replace_na` from the `tidyr`.

```
lapply(list.tib, function(x) x %>% replace_na(list(Value = 50)))

lapply(list.tib, function(x) x %>% mutate(Value = replace_na(Value, 50)))
```

Comment: I think this answer is great because the use of ifelse() allows for a more generalizable value to replace the NA with, which I was looking for in my question.

Answer (score 2):

If `Value` column is present is all data.frames then you can simply write `lapply` as:

```
lapply(split(tib, tib$Group), function(x){
                x$Value[is.na(x$Value)]<-50
                x
                })

# $A
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# Group  Color  Value
# <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>
# 1 A      Red     5.00
# 2 A      Red    50.0 
# 3 A      Red     6.00
# 4 A      Blue   50.0 
# 5 A      Blue   16.0 
# 6 A      Blue   12.0 
# 
# $B
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# Group  Color  Value
# <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>
# 1 B      Red     4.00
# 2 B      Red     5.00
# 3 B      Red     6.00
# 4 B      Blue   10.0 
# 5 B      Blue   12.0 
# 6 B      Blue   17.0
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the final x in the third line of your code?

I understand that the first two lines bring up contents of "Value" for which is.na() = TRUE but I would have thought this would run into a problem when you assign a value to [["B"]]s numeric(0). Somehow, the final x solves this.

I'm sorry this is a basic question, I'll do some reading in the meantime to try to learn.

Comment: Final `x` is to make sure that you return the data frame itself. Otherwise it would return just `Value` column per rule of R to return result of last line.